# I'm getting an error getting the heroku cli properly installed

Tags: heroku, installation

I installed heroku using the instructions on the heroku website.  When I run heroku login (or any other heroku command, I get the output below).  The directory `/home/jsltaic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib` does not exist which I suspect is part of the problem.

```
jsltaic@Ubuntu1204:~$ heroku login
/home/jsltaic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/heroku-2.29.0/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/heroku-2.29.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:15:in `block in load'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/heroku-2.29.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `each'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/heroku-2.29.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `load'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/heroku-2.29.0/lib/heroku/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/heroku-2.29.0/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/jsltaic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to uninstall heroku gem which causes conflicts with CLI

```
gem uninstall heroku
```

Than try if the heroku CLI works, if it doesnt install it again following instructions on this page https://toolbelt.heroku.com/